# Align JButtons in center of nested JPanel (BoxLayout)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, boxlayout

I have a `JFrame`'s child class and have the followiwng layout inside it. I have one big `panel` and one small `buttonsPanel` with two `JButtons`. I add buttons to the smaller panel and add that panel to the first one. Buttons are supposed to be centered, but it doesn't happen.

```
panel=new JPanel();
add(panel);
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

JButton button1=new JButton("button1");
JButton button2=new JButton("button2");

buttonsPanel=new JPanel();
buttonsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonsPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

buttonsPanel.add(button1, CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
buttonsPanel.add(button2, CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
panel.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

What should I do?

Comment: Supposed to be centered vertically, or horizontally?

Comment: @VGR, Horizontaly.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). You need to understand what a "constraint" is and when to use it.

```
buttonsPanel.add(button1, CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
```

The buttons panel uses a BoxLayout. It does not support any constraint, so the CENTER_ALIGNMENT makes no sense.

```
panel.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Again, panel uses a BoxLayout. You can't just use a BorderLayout constraint.

The easiest way to center a component (vertically and horizontally on a frame is to use a GridBagLayout.

So the basic code might be something like:

```
JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
buttonsPanel.add(button1);
buttonsPanel.add(button2);

frame.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
frame.add(buttonsPanel, new GridBagConstraints());
```

If you want to try to use a BoxLayout then you need to use "glue" before and after the panel:

```
Box vertical = Box.createVerticalBox();
vertical.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
vertical.add(buttonsPanel);
vertical.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
```

Again, read the tutorial for more basic information about the `BoxLayout`.

Comment: I added the glue `panel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue())` before and after adding the `buttonsPanel`, removed wrong constrains, but it still doesn't work.

And glue adds empty spaces...

Comment: @parsecer and that is exactly what the glue should do add space at the top and bottom so the component is centered vertically in the middle. If the code isn't working the way you expect then post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.